# How to do join table when using Dynamo DB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, nosql

if there are "Groups" & "Users", each User might belong to different Group,

How can I design the database so that I can easily find

"The common groups the 2 users are both in?"

In SQL, I will do join table, but in DynamoDB, how should I do it?

Comment: That's the thing about NoSQL... it's not the right technology for every job.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to join tables in AWS DynamoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36753861/how-to-join-tables-in-aws-dynamodb)

Answer (score 1):

This is one way of doing it, as suggested by amazon, not nearly as easy as doing joins i sql.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/EMRforDynamoDB.html?tag=duckduckgo-d-20