# How I can join two table in DynamoDb?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, serverless-framework, dynamodb-queries

I am new to DynamoDB, can anyone help me using **JOIN** in DynamoDB? I use Serverless framework and mapping-template. I have table with ***POST*** and ***USER***.
***POST*** has **userId** field. How I can get all posts with info about user ? In MYSQL I can use JOIN but how it work in DynamoDB ? I read posts in stackoverflow created 2 years ago. And guys wrote that it is not available. Maybe something had changed ... ?

Comment: DynamoDB is not a relational database like MySQL is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36753861/how-to-join-tables-in-aws-dynamodb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution. User @eltonio450 on [gitHub](https://github.com/serverless/serverless-graphql/issues/248#issuecomment-404460607) showed how to do this.

Answer (score 12):

DynamoDB is a **NoSQL Database**. This gives it partitioning, incredible performance, scalability, reliability, etc.

The trade-off is that it is **not a relational database**. Therefore, **DynamoDB will not perform a table join**.

You will need to read the tables separately and 'join' desired data within your application.

For example, retrieve the `UserId` from your `Post` table, then retrieve records from the `User` table for the given `UserId`.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you could use Amazon EMR Hadoop to create an `EXTERNAL` Hive table on top of a DynamoDB table; then query the Hive table using HiveQL.

However, the Hive + DynamoDB approach is not recommended; since DynamoDB is designed for low-latency queries. Hive is batch-oriented.

Additionally, Hive might issue a scan (intrinsically inefficient) request to the DynamoDB table(s) before applying any query predicate(s).