# Selecting data in Dynamodb based on values in another field

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have a data dump from Plaid API in DynamoDB. Each transaction has transaction_id, pending(bool), and pending_transaction_id (the FK basically to the older pending transaction it replaces)

```
{
 "account_id": "acct1", // partition key
 "transaction_id": "txn100", // sort key
 "category_id": "22001000",
 "pending": false,
 "pending_transaction_id": "txn1",
 "amount": 500,
},
{
 "account_id": "acct1",
 "transaction_id": "txn1",
 "category_id": "22001000",
 "pending": true,
 "pending_transaction_id": null,
 "amount": 500,
},
```

Is it possible to query in a single query only pending transactions that don't have a permanent replacement yet?

In other words, if it was relational DB it would be along the lines
`select * from txn where pending == false and transaction_id not in (select pending_transaction_id from txn)` (or whatever flavor of CTE or left join you prefer).

How do I do this in dynamo db in a single query?

Comment: It doesn't help anything. You should share the dynamodb table scheme, so we can analyze from.

Comment: DynamoDB isn't designed with comparing (joining) documents (rows) in mind.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36753861/how-to-join-tables-in-aws-dynamodb

Comment: @MatBailie Thank you Mat, that's what I learned now too after watching numerous tutorials. I will either do this in code or redesign the tables. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We can have a GSI here to solve this problem.

| PK (pending) | SK (pending_transaction_id) | .. |
| --- | --- | --- |
| false | txn1 | .. |
| true | null | .. |

We can then query over records which PK and get our records.

Points to consider/ observe:

1. Since SK is null here, record will not be created. This works for us as we don't need those records.
2. We can include `pending = true` records in our GSI if required, however that means having `"NULL"` attribute value.

The advantage with GSI I see here is (considering only pt. 1), we are keeping duplicate records only which we need as part of our query.